# In Hazelcast, how to bypass a near cache for some reads?

Tags: hazelcast

I'm using a near cache for a read-intensive map and it works great. However, once in a while I want to perform a garanteed consistent read, i.e. I want to bypass the near cache.
I can't seem to find this feature in IMap. It seems that once a nearcache is configured, there is no way to access the underlying distributed map.

Maybe there is another pattern for this use case?

Thanks for your help,

Antoine Baudoux

Taktik S.A.

Comment: an interesting question, could be worth investigating this at thte code level. otherwise, you could use 2 (almost) identical maps - if you have memory 2 spare and a extra facade in code maybe. Or you could invalidate the entry before the get :)

Comment: or if you could synchronize access to the map at the time, you could maybe change the config of the map programmatically, I'm not sure if this is possible without reinit, see http://hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#near-cache